Piano fingering for left hand
What's in your opinion the best fingering for left hand:
Tempo: 180

This is m. 12 of Attack On Titan Opening 1 - "Guren No Yumiya", from MuseScore.

At my skill level I’d omit the low A entirely and make it much easier to play. But that’s probably the crux of your question.

As-written fingering recommendation
At quarter-note = 180, this is very difficult. The only fingering that works for me with accuracy is: 5-1  3  2-1  3  5  3  2-1  3.
Seemingly obvious fingering
The most initially obvious fingering, 5-1  5  2-1 ..., is too difficult to play accurately at speed for me to recommend it.
Best option(s)
I think the best option, however, is to drop the initial octave, playing only the upper A. Then the passage can reasonably be played 5  3  2-1  3  5  3  2-1  3. This is also tricky, however, so a further alteration is to drop the A from the A-C# dyad and instead play the entire passage A  E  C#  E  A  E  C#  E using 5  (2 or 3)  1  (2 or 3) ....
Full version

Recommended version(s)


Educated guess: the original is an arrangement from MuseScore made by someone who doesn't know what they're doing.

Thank you for detailed answer

And yes, this is arrangment from MuseScore: musescore.com/user/29818119/scores/6324428#comments

@aress :-) Just leave out the lower note in the octave throughout the arrangement, and it should be fine.

@Aaron Well, the description says it was mostly playable. But the arrangement contains quite unnecessary octaves and stuff, and will probably sound quite bad on a real piano, as everything will be drowned in pedal ...

I'm not sure about the 180 pace, but one technical way to get off that octave in the left hand is to "bounce" from the bottom note through the top, to give your left hand some impetus right-ward. (And then hit the E with your left pinkie, etc.)
Also, conceivably, your right hand could have time to hit some of those left-hand notes, since it's not working so hard? Sometimes such weird ideas really do work, making seemingly-impossible things barely possible. :)
